# Best browser component for multithreaded proxy enabled bots?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, proxy, bots

I'm developing an email/Instagram scraping bot for a user.
The bot should perform searches on google, and then visit a number of web pages retrieved from each search.

I would normally use HTTP requests, but given the circumstances a full browser with script interpreter is needed.

The problem is that the inbuilt web browser control in WinForms, as well as CefSharp just start external browser that is

1. Slow (loading all kind of stuff that is not needed for retrieving simple HTML)
2. Memory intensive (not practical to run 100 instances at the same time)
3. Not independently configurable (one will want to run 30 instances simultaneously, each through a different proxy, or even change proxies for each navigation to new URL e.g.)

So what is the best solution?

Comment: WPF's browser control is something to consider.

Comment: Why? How it's different from the WinForms one?

Comment: When I ask a trivial question it gets negative feedback because my apparent lack of effort, but when I ask a serious question I'm left to answer it myself a week later. And that is how stackoverflow is being counterproductive for me...